# How to work together on Android Studio using github

Tags: android, android-studio, github, project, code-sharing

So me and my friend are working on an android project together but as it happens whenever he shares his code with me it takes a lot of time downloading gradles(which  i already have downloaded.. don't know if its a diff version).

We tried using github to sync our work but seems quite difficult.

It would definitely help us a lot if someone can tell how to work together.
Consider us noobs and please share steps in detail.
Thank you in advance.

**I am on Ubuntu..he is working using Windows.**

Comment: Please see https://medium.com/code-yoga/how-to-link-android-studio-with-github-312037a13b99

Answer (score 1):

you can make that by android studio

1- click VCS

2- Commit - enter your message

3-  VCS > pull

4-  VCS > push

I hope it will work fine with you

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your gradle folder in .gitignore
Gradle dependencies should be built on local and not tracked on git

Comment: dependencies manifest should be on version control though